# Earth Engine Image Collection Reduction Glitch

Tags: google-earth-engine, visualisation, mapping, band

I am having a visual glitch when adding an image as a band to the map. The glitch consists of a vertical line which is not rendered at all. The more I zoom out of the map, the more this line increases in width, When zoomed in, this line decreases in width.

The problem is specifically when I reduce a collection to the last element while filtering its bounds.

```js
var image = imageCollection3.filterBounds(Lixin);
image = image.reduce(ee.Reducer.last());
var NDVI = image.normalizedDifference(['B8_last', 'B4_last']).rename('NDVI');
```

When I try to do the same process by reducing to the sum or the mean, the problem does not happen.

```js
var image = imageCollection3.filterBounds(Lixin);
image = image.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var NDVI = image.normalizedDifference(['B8_mean', 'B4_mean']).rename('NDVI');
```

It is also worth noting I don't get any errors in the console.

This is the link to my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/f512a8c70b5f0d9444285cf190095f43

Is there a way to correct this?

How it looks when reducing to mean/sum:
[image]

How the band looks when reducing to last.
[image: Default Zoom]
[image: Zoom Out]
[image: Increased Zoom Out]
[image: Zoomed In]

Comment: My guess is that there are some nodata or bad values in the NDVI_LI band that you're visualizing. As you zoom, the resampling shifts the missing block around based on the re-drawn grid at each zoom level. I might be wrong, but you can test this by exporting the NDVI_LI image and inspecting for strange values.